# How to know a column which has it's value neither null nor Nope or blank in pandas (per row)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

There is a dataframe - Here I want to find out the last column filled which is neither nan, null, blank nor 'Nope' per row wise:

[image]

Here output is :

```
1 Row: Column (a5)
2 Row: Column (a7)
3 Row: Column (a6)
```

I tried with apply, where I check in reverse order if the value is nan, null, blank nor 'Nope', then drop the column otherwise break the loop and store value.

I want to find a faster way to do this as I'm new to pandas

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a1': [1, 1, 1],
                   'a2': [float('nan'), 1, 1],
                   'a3': [1, 1, 1],
                   'a4': [1, 1, 1],
                   'a5': [1, 1, 1],
                   'a6': ['', 'Nope', 1],
                   'a7': ['', 1, '']})
```

Comment: Please provide your input in a reproducible format (ideally a DataFrame constructor)

Answer (score 2):

For a vectorial solution, you can build a mask with [`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html)/[`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), then get the [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) on the reversed columns:

```
m = ~(df.isnull() | df.isin(['Nope', '']))
# or
# m = df.notnull() & ~df.isin(['Nope', ''])

out = (m.iloc[:, ::-1].idxmax(axis=1)
        [m.any(axis=1)]
      )
```

If you prefer to mask when there is no match:

```
m = ~(df.isnull() | df.isin(['Nope', '']))

out = (m.iloc[:, ::-1].idxmax(axis=1)
        .where(m.any(axis=1))
      )
```

Output:

```
0    a5
1    a7
2    a6
dtype: object
```

Comment: imo looks like you forgot `~` when making `m`

Comment: @Vitalizzare you're right, I just see the "neither", that's why I hate when there is no reproducible input :D

Answer (score 1):

Replace with `nan` what is interpreted as `nan`, then get the last index along the row which points to a solid value, like `sequence.index[~sequence.isna()][-1]`:

```
nan_values = ['Nope','']

last_solid_index = lambda df, axis: (
    df
    .mask(df.isin(nan_values))
    .apply(lambda x: x.index[x.notna()][-1], axis=axis)
)
```

Let's check on the posted data:

```
nan = float('nan')
data = [
    [1,nan,1,1,1,    '',''],
    [1,  1,1,1,1,'Nope', 1],
    [1,  1,1,1,1,     1,''],
]
columns = [f'a{i}' for i in range(1, 8)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(last_solid_index(df, 'columns'))
```

The output:

```
0    a5
1    a7
2    a6
dtype: object
```